# Por que nomes de músicas, livros, filmes e afins são capitalizados?

Tags: ortografia, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Por que a grande maioria das músicas, livros, filmes e títulos em geral são escritos assim: "**Q**ue **P**aís **É** **E**sse",  com todas as iniciais maiúsculas?

Por outro lado, existem títulos assim: "**L**iberdade **o**u **S**olidão", de maneira irregular.

Existe uma convenção para essa capitalização de títulos?

Comment: Títulos em geral o são: livros, filmes, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta é uma pergunta complexa uma vez que não depende só da norma gramatical. Lê [A inicial maiúscula nos títulos -  Cyberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-inicial-maiuscula-nos-titulos/11221):

> A norma portuguesa (acordo de 1945), semelhante neste aspe(c)to à
>   a(c)tual norma brasileira, indica:  «Escrevem-se com maiúsculas
>   iniciais, nas citações, os títulos e subtítulos de `livros, de
>   publicações periódicas e de publicações artísticas´: “*O Primo
>   Basílio*”, (...) “*Diário Oficial*”, “*Revista Lusitana*”, (...) “*O
>   Desterrado*” (estátua de Soares dos Reis), “*O Guarani*” (ópera de Carlos
>   Gomes), “*Transfiguração*” (quadro de Rafael). No entanto, escrevem-se
>   com minúsculas iniciais (ou minúscula exclusiva, se unilíteros), sem
>   prejuízo de haver sempre maiúscula na primeira palavra, os seguintes
>   componentes de títulos e subtítulos deste gé[ê]nero: 1.º) formas do
>   artigo definido ou do pronome demonstrativo afim; 2.º) palavras
>   inflexivas (preposições, advérbios, etc.) simples ou combinadas com as
>   mesmas formas; 3.º locuções relativas a qualquer categoria de palavras
>   inflexivas e combinadas ou não de modo idêntico. Exemplos: (...)
>   “*Algumas Palavras a respeito de Púcaros em Portugal*”.»

E também o [Guia de estilo do Público](http://static.publico.pt/nos/livro_estilo/19-maiuscula-m.html):

> Não se escrevem com inicial maiúscula as partículas monossilábicas,
>   como artigos definidos e contracções ou combinações de palavras
>   inflexivas com esses elementos, nem as palavras inflexivas, a não ser
>   que figurem como primeiro elemento do título, mas escrevem-se com
>   maiúscula inicial os artigos indefinidos e as palavras flexivas: "Sob
>   os Criprestes", "Oração da Coroa", "Agulha em Palheiro", "O Romance de
>   Um Rapaz Pobre". Há elementos que, em títulos, se empregam sempre com
>   inicial maiúscula, como Se, Si e Que: "Quando Se Amava assim", "O
>   Homem Que Ri ", "Castigador de Si Mesmo", "Prática de Oito Figuras".
>   Nos títulos de obras estrangeiras, respeita-se a grafia original.

Ou seja, os monossílabos escrevem-se com letras minúsculas a não ser alguma exceções como o como o Se, o Si e o Que. Correto seria "Que País é Esse" ou "Esse é Que País".

Agora, isso nem sempre tem sentido na prática porque as obras seguem convenções e formatações próprias que ultrapassam as da língua. Experimenta, por exemplo, abrir um jornal qualquer e vai ver que os títulos são sempre em minúsculas salvo a primeira letra e nomes específicos.

Algumas universidades padronizam trabalhos e teses com os títulos sempre em maiúsculas.

No caso das músicas, o artista pode ter uma razão de cunho artístico para mudar a forma como se escreve. Por exemplo, dentro do contexto pode ter sentido mudar a escrita. Por exemplo, se eu quiser enfatizar o Não numa crônica, posso forçar o "Os Homens *Que Não* são Homens *Que Não*".

Daí, uma coisa é a regra, outra é a prática e a formatação. Nem sempre é tão simples diferenciar e também não se pode dizer que seja um erro.

Comment: "Que País É Este" está correto, pelo menos de acordo com o Acordo de 1945, citado no Ciberdúvidas; "Que País é Este" não está. Em caso de dúvida vê [este outro artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/as-maiusculas-nos-titulos-de-uma-bibliografia/13078). Artigos definidos e palavras inflexivas ficam com minúscula; isto inclui *ou, e, mas*; mas não inclui verbos conjugados, mesmo que monosilábicos, como *é, vai*; creio que estas últimas não são consideradas partículas, não ficando portanto abrangidas pelas "partículas monosilábicas" do Guia do Público.