# Uso de vírgula em títulos separados por partes

Tags: ortografia

Gostaria de saber se é correto o uso de vírgula em títulos. É mais adequado utilizar `"Aqui é um lugar ruim, parte 1"` ou `"Aqui é um lugar ruim parte 1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O "Parte N" (ou "Volume", "Tomo", etc.) é tipicamente uma informação sobre o trabalho paralela ao título ou, no máximo, um subtítulo. Mesmo se tornado parte do título, normalmente é separado do restante dele: por vírgula, hífen, dois pontos, nova linha, ou algum outro sinal.

No entanto essa é uma situação ainda menos gramaticalmente regrada que [a das manchetes](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3680/2764), dada a liberdade artística que se pode tomar na escolha do título.

Comment: De acordo com a sua resposta, parece mais uma questão de estilo do autor, onde a vírgula é uma das opções viáveis. De qualquer forma, acredito que você respondeu o que eu queria saber. Obrigado pela ajuda.