# In Portuguese subjects, how to correctly choose upper case and lower case?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Take buzzfeed portuguese for example:

There is a title "Criadores de The Umbrella Academy revelam seus personagens favoritos"

Is it okay to use "Criadores de The Umbrella Academy Revelam Seus Personagens Favoritos"

Comment: you mean in titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay to use "Criadores de The Umbrella Academy Revelam Seus Personagens Favoritos"?

It is ok to use all these upper cases in the context you mentioned: an internet post title... but it is not usual. In Brazilian Portuguese we use upper cases in the following situations:

1 - Beginning of sentences

2 - Names. All kinds of names. People names, institution names, movies.... (Encontrei a *Marcela* no mercado / Criadores de *The Umbrella Academy* revelam seus personagens favoritos / Eu fui ao *Instituto Brasileiro de Geografia e Estatística*)

3 - Holidays and celebration dates (Vou encontrar a *Marcela* no *Natal*)

4 - Acronyms, symbols and abbreviations (IBGE - Instituto Brasileiro de Geografia e Estatística)

Also, as said @stafusa, take a look at this: [Por que nomes de músicas, livros, filmes e afins são capitalizados?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/por-que-nomes-de-m%C3%BAsicas-livros-filmes-e-afins-s%C3%A3o-capitalizados)

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but in news sources it's way more usual to have only the first word capitalized in the headlines/titles - as a visit to any Brazilian or Portuguese newspaper website can attest.

Thus, the Original Post's first version of the title is preferred, but the second one is not wrong, though even there, the word "seus" should probably not be capitalized (the same way "de" already isn't).

I couldn't find sources in English, some in Portuguese are [this](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/nao-tropece-detail.php?id=417), [this](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-inicial-maiuscula-nos-titulos/11221), and [this](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/maiusculas-em-titulos/8816), besides the question [Por que nomes de músicas, livros, filmes e afins são capitalizados?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3679/2764).