# Como escrever nomes próprios com hífen quando num título?

Tags: maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Quando escrevemos título, pomos algumas palavras com sua primeira letra maiúscula, como «O **B**om, o **M**au e o **F**eio». E nomes próprios também, «O enxadeiro é o **A**ntônio».

Mas como devemos fazer isto a palavras com hífen? Deve ser «A História do **A**dvogado-**S**anto» ou «A História do **A**dvogado-**s**anto», ou ainda outra coisa?

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que nomes de músicas, livros, filmes e afins são capitalizados?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3679/2764).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se trata de um nome próprio normalmente [escreve-se](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/maiusculas-nos-compostos/23438) com maiúscula ambas as partes, mesmo que não faça parte de um título, portanto: "Advogado-Santo", se é assim que ele é chamado.